# Is there a way to trigger a callback after tooltip text is displayed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I have a button that has a default tooltip text that is suppose to show whenever user hovers mouse on it e.g. "Fill all the forms", however when user sets something wrong e.g. they fill out a form with wrong info, and press the button it should show a different tooltip text with an error message for that same button, the problem is that when a different tooltip text is set to that button by using `tooltip.Show(String, IWin32Window)` method, so it overrides the previous tooltip text I have set to that button and makes the error message always show instead of its default tooltip text e.g. "Fill all the forms". I tried to implement `Draw` and `Popup` events to turn back to its default tooltip text but `Popup` is triggered before tooltip text is displayed and `Draw` displays a blank tooltip text. So I think a callback would be a workaround to set the default tooltip text back after the error message is displayed.

Comment: You can call `[ToolTip].SetToolTip(Control, Caption)` based on a condition. Setting the Tooltip text in the designer is not required.

Comment: I'd use the `ErrorProvider` for the error part.

Comment: @Jimi `SetToolTip` had the same effect as the `Show` method, it still overrides my previous tooltip text making the error message always ON when user hovers mouse on that particular button, I'm not sure if I was clear enough, but I want a way to set the tooltip text of a button to string X and string Y will only display when an error occurs, so after the error gets displayed by string Y it should get back to string X, so the next time user hovers the mouse on the button it will display string X not Y.

Comment: Wire the Enter and MouseEnter event to the same handler, then: `if (errorCondition) { toolTip1.SetToolTip(someButton, "Error Condition"); } else { toolTip1.SetToolTip(someButton, "Normal Condition"); }`. Set `errorCondition` based on the validation procedure you have. Take into consideration what @dr.null proposed.

Comment: I decided to have a go on `ErrorProvider`, actually it went well so I'm closing this question, thanks @dr.null and @Jimi .